# Как выводить эти категории в постах?

Tags: wordpress

Всем добрый день!
Есть:
custom post type - "services" и
custom taxonomy - "services_category".
И есть такая структура таксономии:

```
bmw
 - bmw e60/61
    - bmw 520d
       - Техобслуживание
               (Пост: Тех. обслуживание для bmw 520d)
       - Дооснащение
       - Ремонт
         - Ремонт двигателя
                 (Пост: Ремонт двигателя bmw 520d)
         - Ремонт АКПП
                 (Пост: Замена масла АКПП bmw 520d)
    - bmw 530i
       - Техобслуживание
               (Пост: Тех. обслуживание для bmw 530i)
       - Дооснащение
       - Ремонт
         - Ремонт двигателя
                 (Пост: Ремонт двигателя bmw 530i)
         - Ремонт АКПП
                 (Пост: Замена масла АКПП bmw 530i)
```

Как в этих постах, выводить список основных категорий этой модели? А именно, как вывести в сайдбаре ссылки на: Ремонт, Техобслуживание, Дооснащение? и именно от этой модели, в которой находится пост?
Хочу сделать навигацию по всем основным категориям каждой модели.
Вот как здесь - https://www.autoservice-audi.ru/inf/a6/akpp/ левое меню

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода в sidebar Вам нужно пройти следующие этапы

1. Инициализировать свой виджет - прописать вызов его в functions.php вашей темы либо в плагине

Примерный код

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
 
    public function __construct() {
        // actual widget processes
    }
 
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }
 
    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form in the admin
    }
 
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpdocs_register_widgets' );
 
function wpdocs_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/

2. Реализовать вывод списка категорий

```
<?php
if ( is_singular( 'services' ) ) {
        
        $post_id = get_the_ID();    

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'services_category'); ?>
         <ul>
                 <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                        <?php if ($term -> parent) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term_ ); ?>"><?php echo $term -> name ; ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         <?php
    }
```

3. В админке назначить вывод вашего виджета в нужный сайдбар
4. Примерный код виджета

```
function services_category_register_widget() {
    register_widget( 'services_category_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'services_category_register_widget' );

class services_category_widget extends WP_Widget {
    
 function __construct() {
    
     parent::__construct(
                              // widget ID
                              'services_category_widget',
                              // widget name
                             __('Services Category Widget', ' services_category_widget_domain'),
                             // widget description
                             array( 'description' => __( 'Services Categor Widget', 'services_category_widget_domain' ), )
                         );
 }
 public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    
    if ( is_singular( 'services' ) ) {
        
        $post_id = get_the_ID();    

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        
        //if title is present
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        //output
        ?>
        <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'services_category'); ?>
         <ul>
                 <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                        <?php if ($term -> parent) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term_ ); ?>"><?php echo $term -> name ; ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         <?php
         echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
 }
 
 public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) )
    $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    else
    $title = __( 'Default Title', 'services_category_widget_domain' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
 }
 public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
 }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Но проблема в том, что get_the_terms выводит только те категории, которые непосредственно относятся к посту. Но надо эти выводить, и я не знаю как https://prnt.sc/v2yoj1

Comment: @aidar в вопросе не достаточно данных для ответа

Comment: get_the_terms выводит вот эти категории, которые отмечаются в админке - https://prnt.sc/v2znlo но я хочу не их выводить, а те которые под bmw 520d - https://prnt.sc/v2zoyc